# urls for specific parts of a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, .htaccess

I have a marquee that I use on every single page (part of the navigationbar), It has a few different lines it can chose to echo 1 line at a time. One of those contain a link `<a href="/link" class="a">link</a>` how can i make it redirect me to a specific part of the index?

I found this

```
$(function(){
  var tempDiv = $("<div />");
  tempDiv.load("page-to-load.htm", function() {
        var content = tempDiv.find("#main");
        var title = tempDiv.find("title");
        var nav = tempDiv.find("ul.nav");
  });
});
```

But not sure how it works.
for a better understanding of what i am looking for http://www.swtor.com/dark-vs-light/home (best link i could find that have this).

by changing the url from `/home` to something like `/pack` it scrolls down to a different div.

I use same class on many different divs on the index so if it could work with id or name that whould be better. but could someone please explain how this work and if possible to link from one page to another by using `/link`? (can use .htaccess for mod rewrite)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for anchor which is done using a combination of id attribute and links. The anchor on the link must be the id that you give to the element to you want to reach.

Example:

```
<a href="#intro">Introduction</a>
<div id="intro">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore animi enim, beatae vitae nostrum ad, necessitatibus sit aperiam perferendis impedit nemo, saepe! Inventore quam aliquid laboriosam dolor perspiciatis, nemo a.
</div>
```

Comment: that was way easier then id expected, thanks alot :)

Comment: You welcome @AvatarLandRazer ! It's always nice to see that the current implementation in browser covers your needs. Don't forget to put it as the correct answer for other people that will have the same question.

Comment: ye, was just waiting for the timer so i could accept it :)